# Unable to Delete a List of Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having an issue when trying to delete an object with multiple items returned in it. When I run the below code I get the following error:

"InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Test.Models.TournamentDetails]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Test.Models.TournamentDetails'."

I don't understand why I am not able to return my model? I've tried a handful of other fixes posted on stack overflow with no luck... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*** Index View ***

```
 @model IEnumerable<TournamentDetails>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TournamentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TournamentNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HandTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-controller="TournamentDetails" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.TournamentNumber"
            class="btn btn-danger mx-2"> <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}

*** Controller ***

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? Id)
    {
        var result = _context.TournamentDetails.Where(b => b.TournamentNumber.Equals(Id)).ToList();

        return View(result);
    }

[HttpPost,ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePost(int? Id)
{
    var obj = _context.TournamentDetails.Where(b => b.TournamentNumber.Equals(Id));
     _context.TournamentDetails.RemoveRange(obj);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

*** Delete View ***

```
@model TournamentDetails

<form method="post" asp-controller="TournamentDetails" asp-action="DeleteTournament">
    <input asp-for="TournamentNumber" hidden />
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Delete Tournament</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="TournamentName"></label>
            <input asp-for="TournamentName" disabled class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:150px">Delete</button>
        <a asp-controller="TournamentDetails" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Back to List
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post more code of controller? such as what is the action `DeleteTournament`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Delete View is expecting the (single) model with `Test.Models.TournamentDetails` type.

```
@model TournamentDetails
```

However, your "Delete" Controller action is returning multiple items: ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Test.Models.TournamentDetails] ```

```cs
var result = _context.TournamentDetails
    .Where(b => b.TournamentNumber.Equals(Id))
    .ToList();
```

I leave it to you to think that do the `TournamentNumber` is a unique value in the `TournamentDetails` table.

If the answer is **yes**,

You should return only a single entry with either of these methods:

1. [`.Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-7.0). Return only a single record. Note that it will throw an exception when there are multiple entries with the same `TournamentNumber` or no entry is found.
2. [`.SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-7.0). Return only a single record or `null`. Note that it will throw an exception when there are multiple entries with the same `TournamentNumber`.
3. [`.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-7.0). Return the first matching record. Note that it will throw an exception when no entry is found.
4. [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-7.0). Return the first matching record or `null`.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? Id)
{
    var result = _context.TournamentDetails
        .SingleOrDefault(b => b.TournamentNumber.Equals(Id));

    if (result == null)
        return NotFound();

    return View(result);
}
```

Also, you should delete only a single entry by Id instead of multiple entries.

```cs
[HttpPost,ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePost(int? Id)
{
    var obj = _context.TournamentDetails
        .SingleOrDefault(b => b.TournamentNumber.Equals(Id));
    _context.TournamentDetails.Remove(obj);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

If the answer is **no**, you need to think about these questions.

1. Are you trying to delete a single entry or multiple entries?
2. If deleting a single entry, use and search the entry with the primary key/unique column of the `TournamentDetails` table.
3. If deleting multiple entries, is it correct to show multiple entries that the view is expecting to receive only a single entry?

---

Perspectives, Recommendations

1. It is weird that you allow the `Id` parameter to be nullable for the "Delete" and "DeletePost" actions. Definitely, you **need an `Id` to perform edit/delete operations for the specific entry**. Would suggest removing the nullable `?` for `Id`.
2. As both of your actions are asynchronous, you may fully utilize the await/async operation to fetch data. For example,

```cs
var obj = await _context.TournamentDetails
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.TournamentNumber.Equals(Id));
```

3. Bear in mind when you are deleting entry(s), you may take the potential risk that you will lose the data or even the whole data for the table entirely.

   The `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute is one of the ways to prevent the attack of losing the data. You may also consider the soft-delete approach.